# DRY way to add same condition on many queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use rails 3.0.5

I've `User` and `Company` models, a user `belongs_to` a `Company`.

The `Product`, `Bill`, a several others also `belongs_to` a `Company`.

For obvious reasons, a `User` can acts on a `Product`, `Bill`... only if the `Product's` `Company` is the same as the `User's` `Company`.

I can use custom scope queries adding the condition on the company for everything, but it's not DRY at all.

How would you do that the the nice way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@product = current_user.company.products.find params[:id]
```

should work. If you want to DRY it up further I'd recommend using the plugin [InheritedResources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) which has a sweet method called `begin_of_association_chain` (see in the README under overwriting defaults) that let's you define this stuff globally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into named scopes? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Seems like exactly what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for your comment, using scope will do the job, but I'll have to repeat the same scope for each model, and each time I fetch data in controllers I'll have to use this scope, I'm looking for a more DRY method

Answer (score 0):

You can define a association

> has_many :products, :through => :company

Then you can do

> user.products.find(params[:id])

Not sure if this is the right way to do it!!!